# I cannot log in on stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, user-accounts

When I try to log in with my email, I get this error:[image: Oops! Something Bad Happened!]

My email is a Gmail one. When I try to log in using Google, I get this error: [image: There was an error fetching your account from Google. Please try logging in again.]

When I try to create an account, I get this error: [image: Email already in use.]

I maintain active profiles on several stackexchange sites such as mathematics: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/469826/dapianoman

I suspect that different sites have different password requirements and this may have something to do with my error. When I try to create an account on stackexchange.com with the same login and password credentials I use on math.stackexchange.com, I get a notification that the password is not secure enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you also have two distinct accounts with two distinct sets of credentials. Somehow se.com has got its wires crossed and thought the se.com profiles for both belonged to the same account id. I fixed that up, so you should be able to log in there now.